# How / where do you search for installed java libraries on your computer / project?

Tags: java, eclipse, enfinity, intershop

I don't have a good understanding about how Java and Eclipse (more specifically, Enfinity) arrange their project files. I'm part of a team at my office which working on a project which continuing the working of many other past members of the team. Many of the original people who worked for this project on the earlier days is already not here, so I can't ask them, or ask anybody else.

Here's the problem: I need to understand how a class is working before I can find what's wrong with the result. But after some tracking with Java decompiler (jd-gui), I'm stuck to a class that's referred on the line `import de.factfinder.search.Search;`. I can't find that anywhere. If you're debugging on an unfamiliar computer using Java decompiler, and you find an import reference to a class like this, where would you suggest to start looking? What filename it might be contained on?

Note for Enfinity users: I've also already searched thoroughly on the folder that has `bc_foundation` and friends, where usually Enfinity proprietary classes stored and I can't find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the library is already configured in your project. Then, you could try to search the class through "Open Type" dialog which accessible via shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>.

On the dialog, you then search the class by typing its name (in this case `de.factfinder.search.Search`) and then you can look at the bottom text area where the package is.

Example is like this, let say I want to search `Entity` annotation where the jar file is.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: OOOOH! It did appear after I typed in the `de.factfinder.search.Search`, complete with the path to the jar library where it stored! Why I never know about this miraculous CTRL+SHIFT+T shortcut?? This is what I've been looking for all this time! Thank you flying_cat! :D

Comment: Well, now you know that (and a few Malay or Indonesian);)

Answer (score 1):

It's in one of the jar files on your classpath. In Eclipse, select pull-down menu Navigate > Open Type... and enter the full class name. Then select pull-down menu Navigate > Show In... > Package Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I never knew about that. Learning java by autodidact, I have many things missing from the basics. Thanks!